# Subdivision surface creating face where it shouldn't

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

So the thing is i'm modelling or trying to model a toilet, but when I'm going to use the subdivision surface modifier it kind of tries to close up the toilet, well, entrance, openning, whole... How can I fix that?

[image: This is before the subdivision surface modifier]

[image: This is after the subdivision surface modifier]

Comment: It is better to assume you are not doing something right when learning and something goes wrong instead of assuming the tool does not work as it should. Subsurf is creating faces exactly where it is supposed to create them in your images. It might seem like a pointless observation, but think about it: if the tool is broken there is not much you can do about it, it is not clear what you should or could do and you are stuck, however if you do not have the necessary knowledge to use it, it is very easy to fix - just find out how it works. That frame of mind is actually very useful when learning.

Comment: You need more geometry to describe such a curved surface at the top edge of the toilet bowl. The subdivision surface is working correctly by interpolating between the existing vertices.

Comment: I didn't mean the tool was broken, I just meant its not the way I want, sorry for the misunderstanding. Thanks for the advice Martin, I am indeed new at this. What tools should I add more geometry?  I've tried adding loop cuts but it wasn't enough

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You need to create edges with the vertex of the inside hole with the vertices of the outer ring

Comment: you can also try creases - SHIFT + E

Answer (score 1):

The reason subdivision surface is "closing up" the hole for the toilet basin is because you have no vertex information to continue subdividing from there.

Subdivision surface attempts to take a single face or edge and *divide* (hence the name) it into multiple parts. (Two parts if an edge, four if its a face)

Blender currently supports two modes of subdividing, Catmull-Clark and Simple. Catmull-Clark subdividing subdivides and attempts to smooth out the new faces by determining the proximity of each face to each other, thus creating a roundish shape. Simple subdividing subdivides each face, while retaining the original shape of the object.

If you have an unclosed portion of a mesh which you are subdividing, the dividing and smoothing of the faces on the unclosed edge will smooth and start to draw closer to each other.

In your case, you should probably either extrude the face further into the basin and close it up at the bottom, or extrude it and form a pipe or something out the back of the toilet if you don't plan to close the mesh up.

This would make the smoothing of the modifier less visible at the mouth of the toilet, and give you a better result.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: me no see image. me can't read. me downvote.